# Moving average over 5 years with irregular dates

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a large number of files (~1200) which each contains a large timeserie with data about the height of the groundwater. The starting date and length of the serie is different for each file. There can be large data gaps between dates, for example (small part of such a file):

```
Date        Height (cm)
14-1-1980   7659
28-1-1980   7632
14-2-1980   7661
14-3-1980   7638
28-3-1980   7642
14-4-1980   7652
25-4-1980   7646
14-5-1980   7635
29-5-1980   7622
13-6-1980   7606
27-6-1980   7598
14-7-1980   7654
28-7-1980   7654
14-8-1980   7627
28-8-1980   7600
12-9-1980   7617
14-10-1980  7596
28-10-1980  7601
14-11-1980  7592
28-11-1980  7614
11-12-1980  7650
29-12-1980  7670
14-1-1981   7698
28-1-1981   7700
13-2-1981   7694
17-3-1981   7740
30-3-1981   7683
14-4-1981   7692
14-5-1981   7682
15-6-1981   7696
17-7-1981   7706
28-7-1981   7699
28-8-1981   7686
30-9-1981   7678
17-11-1981  7723
11-12-1981  7803
18-2-1982   7757
16-3-1982   7773
13-5-1982   7753
11-6-1982   7740
14-7-1982   7731
15-8-1982   7739
14-9-1982   7722
14-10-1982  7794
15-11-1982  7764
14-12-1982  7790
14-1-1983   7810
28-3-1983   7836
28-4-1983   7815
31-5-1983   7857
29-6-1983   7801
28-7-1983   7774
24-8-1983   7758
28-9-1983   7748
26-10-1983  7727
29-11-1983  7782
27-1-1984   7801
28-3-1984   7764
27-4-1984   7752
28-5-1984   7795
27-7-1984   7748
27-8-1984   7729
28-9-1984   7752
26-10-1984  7789
28-11-1984  7797
18-12-1984  7781
28-1-1985   7833
21-2-1985   7778
22-4-1985   7794
28-5-1985   7768
28-6-1985   7836
26-8-1985   7765
19-9-1985   7760
31-10-1985  7756
26-11-1985  7760
20-12-1985  7781
17-1-1986   7813
28-1-1986   7852
26-2-1986   7797
25-3-1986   7838
22-4-1986   7807
27-5-1986   7785
24-6-1986   7787
26-8-1986   7744
23-9-1986   7742
22-10-1986  7752
1-12-1986   7749
17-12-1986  7758
```

I want to calculate the average height over 5 years. So, in case of the example 14-1-1980 + 5 years, 14-1-1985 + 5 years, .... The amount of datapoints is different for each calculation of the average. It is very likely that the date 5 years later will not be in the dataset as a datapoint. Hence, I think I need to tell R somehow to take an average in a certain timespan.

I searched on the internet but didn't find something that fitted my needs. A lot of useful packages like uts, zoo, lubridate and the function aggregate passed by. Instead of getting closer to the solution I get more and more confused about which approach is the best for my problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: to begin with you could read them all and rbind into one single dataframe .

Comment: Maybe have a look at `rollapply` in the `zoo` package.

Answer (score 5):

As @vagabond points out, you'll want to combine your 1200 files into a single data frame (the *plyr* package would allow you to do something simple like: `data.all <- adply(dir([DATA FOLDER]), 1, read.csv)`.

Once you have the data, the first step would be to transform the `Date` column into proper POSIXct date data. Right now the data appear to be strings, and we want them to have an underlying numerical representation (which POSIXct does):

```
library(lubridate)
df$date.new <- as.Date(dmy(df$Date))

       Date Height   date.new
1 14-1-1980   7659 1980-01-14
2 28-1-1980   7632 1980-01-28
3 14-2-1980   7661 1980-02-14
4 14-3-1980   7638 1980-03-14
5 28-3-1980   7642 1980-03-28
6 14-4-1980   7652 1980-04-14
```

Note that the `date.new` column looks like a string, but is in fact Date data, and can be handled with numerical operations (addition, comparison, etc.).

Next, we might construct a set of date periods, over which we want to compute averages. Your example mentions 5 years, but with the data you provided, that's not a very illustrative example. So here I'm creating 1-year periods starting at every day between Jan 14 1980 and Jan 14 1985

```
date.start <- as.Date(as.Date('1980-01-14') : as.Date('1985-01-14'), origin = '1970-01-01')
date.end <- date.start + years(1)
dates <- data.frame(start = date.start, end = date.end)

       start        end
1 1980-01-14 1981-01-14
2 1980-01-15 1981-01-15
3 1980-01-16 1981-01-16
4 1980-01-17 1981-01-17
5 1980-01-18 1981-01-18
6 1980-01-19 1981-01-19
```

Then we can use the *dplyr* package to move through each row of this data frame and compute a summary average of `Height`:

```
library(dplyr)
df.mean <- dates %>% 
    group_by(start, end) %>% 
    summarize(height.mean = mean(df$Height[df$date.new >= start & df$date.new < end]))

       start        end height.mean
      <date>     <date>       <dbl>
1 1980-01-14 1981-01-14    7630.273
2 1980-01-15 1981-01-15    7632.045
3 1980-01-16 1981-01-16    7632.045
4 1980-01-17 1981-01-17    7632.045
5 1980-01-18 1981-01-18    7632.045
6 1980-01-19 1981-01-19    7632.045
```

Comment: As I interpreted it, @BartM is looking for the average of the datapoints that lie between a date and 5 years ahead of that date. You are also creating new periods for each missing date. that isn't what BartM asked imho.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous on that point, but if you wanted periods based only on the dates present in the existing data, `dates.start <- df$date.new` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The `foverlaps` function is IMHO the perfect candidate for such a situation:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# convert to a data.table with setDT()
# convert the 'Date'-column to date-format
# create a begin & end date for the required period
setDT(dat)[, Date := as.Date(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')                      
           ][, `:=` (begindate = Date, enddate = Date + years(1))]

# set the keys (necessary for the foverlaps function)
setkey(dat, begindate, enddate)

res <- foverlaps(dat, dat, by.x = c(1,3))[, .(moving.average = mean(i.Height)), Date]
```

the result:

```
> head(res,15)
          Date moving.average
 1: 1980-01-14       7633.217
 2: 1980-01-28       7635.000
 3: 1980-02-14       7637.696
 4: 1980-03-14       7636.636
 5: 1980-03-28       7641.273
 6: 1980-04-14       7645.261
 7: 1980-04-25       7644.955
 8: 1980-05-14       7646.591
 9: 1980-05-29       7647.143
10: 1980-06-13       7648.400
11: 1980-06-27       7652.900
12: 1980-07-14       7655.789
13: 1980-07-28       7660.550
14: 1980-08-14       7660.895
15: 1980-08-28       7664.000
```

Now you have for each date an average of all the values that lie the date and one year ahead of that date.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I just tried after seeing your question!!! Ran on a sample data frame. Try it on yours after understanding the code and then let me know!

Bdw instead of having an interval of 5 years, I used just 2 months (2*30 = approx 2 months) as the interval!

```
df = data.frame(Date = c("14-1-1980", "28-1-1980", "14-2-1980", "14-3-1980", "28-3-1980",
                     "14-4-1980", "25-4-1980", "14-5-1980", "29-5-1980", "13-6-1980:",
                     "27-6-1980", "14-7-1980", "28-7-1980", "14-8-1980"), height = 1:14)

# as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")

df1 = data.frame(orig = NULL, dest = NULL, avg_ht = NULL)
orig = as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")[1]
dest = as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")[1] + 2*30 #approx 2 months
dest_final = as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")[14]

while (dest < dest_final){
  m = mean(df$height[which(as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")>=orig &
                           as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")<dest )])
  df1 = rbind(df1,data.frame(orig=orig,dest=dest,avg_ht=m))
  orig = dest
  dest = dest + 2*30
  print(paste("orig:",orig, " + ","dest:",dest))
}

> df1
        orig       dest avg_ht
1 1980-01-14 1980-03-14    2.0
2 1980-03-14 1980-05-13    5.5
3 1980-05-13 1980-07-12    9.5
```

I hope this works for you as well

Comment: since I'm using while() loop , the code is going to be slow. But i hope that this gives you an actual start to your exploration!! update me with the results!

Comment: Your example worked well, I'll see how it works out when I run it on alles the files. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This is my best try, but please keep in mind that I am working with the years instead of the full date, i.e. based on the example you provided I am averaging over beginning of 1980- end of 1984.

```
dat<-read.csv("paixnidi.csv")
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
dates<-dat[,1]
#extract the year of each measurement
years<-as.integer(str_sub(dat[,1], start= -4))
spread_y<-years[length(years)]-years[1]

ind<-list()
#find how many 5-year intervals there are
groups<-ceiling(spread_y/4)
meangroups<-matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=groups)
k<-0
for (i in 1:groups){
  #extract the indices of the dates vector whithin the 5-year period
  ind[[i]]<-which(years>=(years[1]+k)&years<=(years[1]+k+4),arr.ind=TRUE)
  meangroups[i,2]<-mean(dat[ind[[i]],2])
  meangroups[i,1]<-(years[1]+k)
  k<-k+5
}

colnames(meangroups)<-c("Year:Year+4","Mean Height (cm)")
```